# R: Box Plot - How to move x and y axis to be visible?

Tags: r

```
ana1$B<-factor(ana1$Burn,c("C","N","L","S"))
with(ana1,boxplot(Time~ana1$B, ylab  = "Infiltration Rate (mm/h) " , xlab ="Burn Treatment", las = 2, par(mar = c(12, 5, 4, 2)+0.1), names = c( "Control" , "Not burned since 1954" , "Long rotation burn" , "Short rotation burn" ) ) )
```

Hi, this is my current code, which creates axis titles that are obstructed by my rotated labels. Does any one know how to move both of the axis titles across and down?

I am really struggling with this, although the solution may be very easy!

[image]

So I have alerted the code, however now the x axis label has gone off the box plot entirely

```
    ana1$B<-factor(ana1$Burn,c("C","N","L","S"))
    with(ana1,boxplot(Time~ana1$B, ylab  = "Infiltration Rate (mm/h) " , xlab = "", las = 2, par(mar = c(12, 4, 4, 1)+0.1), title("Burn Treatment", line = 10), names = c( "Control" , "Not burned since 1954" , "Long rotation burn" , "Short rotation burn" ) ) )
```

The parameter has changed but the x axis label has disappeared

[Updated boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV6c9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `title` to manually draw an axis title, and adjust its position through the `line` parameter. For example, for the x axis, you can do

```
par(mar = c(12, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1);
boxplot(df, xlab = "", las = 2);
title(xlab = "Burn Treatment", line = 10);
```

[image]

You can increase the plot margin using `par(mar = ...)`. You'll probably need to tweak the parameters `par(mar = ...)` and `title(..., line = ...)` for your data.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- data.frame(
    'Control' = rnorm(100),
    'Not burned since 1954' = rnorm(100),
    'Long rotation burn' = rnorm(100),
    'Short rotation burn' = rnorm(100))
```

---

### Update

The following should work with your data:

```
par(mar = c(12, 4, 4, 1) + 0.1);       # This sets the plot margins
with(                                  # Draw the boxplot
    ana1,
    boxplot(
        Time ~ B, 
        ylab  = "Infiltration Rate (mm/h) " , 
        xlab = "", 
        las = 2, 
        names = c("Control" , "Not burned since 1954" , "Long rotation burn" , "Short rotation burn")));
title(xlab = "Burn Treatment", line = 10);    # Add x axis title
```

You might have to play around with `line = 10` and try different values; ditto for the plot margins. The first number in `mar = c(12, 4, 4, 2)` gives the bottom margin, see `?par` for details.

Comment: hi, so I am very new to r and I understand what you mean but I am not able to format this into my own code without it saying error.

Comment: ana1$B<-factor(ana1$Burn,c("C","N","L","S"))
with(ana1,boxplot(Time~ana1$B, ylab  = "Infiltration Rate (mm/h) " , xlab = "Burn Treatment", las = 2, par(mar = c(12, 4, 4, 2)+0.1), boxplot(df, xlab =  "", las = 2) title(xlab =  "Burn Treatment", line = 10),  names = c( "Control" , "Not burned since 1954" , "Long rotation burn" , "Short rotation burn" ) ) )

Comment: that is how I have written the new code, however I am sure I have gone wrong and gotten confused as it says error every time I run it through R

Comment: @BelleT Please don't put extended code in comments; it makes it very difficult/impossible to read. You can edit your original question to include your sample code and sample data.

Comment: sorry I am new to this website also. I have edited my original question and since altered the code, so now it does not say there is an error, it just makes the x axis label disappear! I appreciate your help, I am finding R rather challenging and have been asked to give it a go for a university project

Comment: @BelleT No need to apologise; I've edited my solution, please take a look. There are some great resources available on SO (for example how to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), including sample data) that will help you improve the quality of future questions, and attract more attention.

Comment: If I copy this into R should it work? or do I need to do something to it? at the moment when I run it, the only axis label appearing is the y axis which is overlapped

Comment: @BelleT Ah sorry; I made a mistake in the update; it should have been `title(xlab = "...", line = 10)` just like in the first bit of my solution.

Comment: @BelleT Did this solve your problem? If so, you can close the question by setting the tick mark next to the answer.